# SP2016 - Adding links to Suite Bar - Partial answer found, need help from JS experts

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, suite

I have been researching for endless hours to find a script that enables me to add links to the suite bar in SP2016 On Prem. There are many solutions for SP2013 but they just do not work with SP2016 (style codes n functions changed?).

I have found one that works lovely BUT it has a delay on page load (this is reported as a common issue with this script). I have found the answer to it on another thread on Stack Exchange but regretfully the answer was to wrap it in some JS and I just do not know how to do this, the answer didn't show a complete script so I am back to square 1 -( ... can anyone help with providing the finished script?

INITIAL SCRIPT THAT WORKS (but with delay on page load)

```
<script>
var raiseFunc = function() {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var linktext = document.createTextNode("Google");
    link.href = "http://www.google.ca"
    link.setAttribute("class", "o365button o365cs-nav-appTitle o365cs- topnavText");
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.appendChild(linktext);
    span.setAttribute("class", "o365cs-nav-brandingText");
    link.appendChild(span);
    var temp = document.getElementById("Sites_BrandBar");
    temp.parentElement.appendChild(link);
};

_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(raiseFunc);
</script>
```

**THE APPARENT FIX** ([Add link to sharepoint suite bar - fail on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061058/add-link-to-sharepoint-suite-bar-fail-on-first-load/49922497#49922497))

*Try to make your add link into a function and use*

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext', yourFunctionToInsertHere);
```

I believe it's the sp.js that is not loading before you are trying to add it. This should delay your add until it's loaded. (the author reported this as working well)

===========================================

How do I incorporate this fix into the original script?

Many thanks, **Julie** -)

Answer (score 1):

The way that I do it, I being the Matt that answered it in the question you linked to, is I user jquery's `$(document).ready(function(){});` The way I do it exactly is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', raiseFunc());
});

function raiseFunc() {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var linktext = document.createTextNode("Google");
    link.href = "http://www.google.ca"
    link.setAttribute("class", "o365button o365cs-nav-appTitle o365cs- topnavText");
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.appendChild(linktext);
    span.setAttribute("class", "o365cs-nav-brandingText");
    link.appendChild(span);
    var temp = document.getElementById("Sites_BrandBar");
    temp.parentElement.appendChild(link);
};
```

Keep in mind this is for doing work with lists and not what we do for the links or main navigation. I cannot promise this will fix your issues. If you cannot use jQuery then I do believe there are other work arounds for timing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems caused by DOM not initialize for first time load. 
So I add time out to fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var raiseFunc = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            var linktext = document.createTextNode("Google");
            link.href = "http://www.google.ca"
            link.setAttribute("class", "o365button o365cs-nav-appTitle o365cs- topnavText");
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.appendChild(linktext);
            span.setAttribute("class", "o365cs-nav-brandingText");
            link.appendChild(span);
            var temp = document.getElementById("Sites_BrandBar");
            temp.parentElement.appendChild(link);
        },500);
    }
        _spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(raiseFunc);        
    </script>
```

Even I tried `SP.SOD.executeFunc`, the issue exists.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
                 var link = document.createElement('a');
            var linktext = document.createTextNode("Google");
            link.href = "http://www.google.ca"
            link.setAttribute("class", "o365button o365cs-nav-appTitle o365cs- topnavText");
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.appendChild(linktext);
            span.setAttribute("class", "o365cs-nav-brandingText");
            link.appendChild(span);
            var temp = document.getElementById("Sites_BrandBar");
            temp.parentElement.appendChild(link);
            });       
    </script>
```

Comment: So there's no event we can hook for this, we have to just guess a timeout? :-(

Comment: You may try this https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/how-to-detect-if-element-is-added-or-removed-from-dom/ (I haven't test this).